# Difference in image size using File.stream

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am sending image file in response using `send_resp(200,content)`

I have used `Stream` for lazy loading the file

```
File.stream!(fullpath)
|> Stream.map(fn e -> e end) 
|> Enum.reduce(<<>>, fn x,acc  -> acc <> x end)
```

My original file size on disk is 1615829 bytes.

If I do `File.read(fullpath)` (eager loading) I get the exact file of size 1615829.

But by using `File.stream` the image file received is of 1615792 (37 bytes less).

Image is getting blurred because of this.

Which bits I am missing? Am  I using `File.stream` correctly here?

Comment: Make sure you are formally closing the file using `File.close` https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/File.html#close/1

Comment: Also take a look at https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/File.html#stream!/3 and what it says about Raw Files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is hard to tell what is wrong outside the code you’ve shown, but this code is surely a) fine and b) meaningless.

`Enum.reduce/3` (as all the functions from `Enum` module) does indeed terminate the stream. That said, lines

```rb
fullpath
|> File.stream!()
|> Stream.map(& &1) 
|> Enum.reduce("", &2 <> &1)
```

do essentially the same as `File.read!/1` (might be less effectively). You might check they return the correct expected result, but they *do it immediately*.

```rb
with :ok <- File.write!("test.txt", "a\x00\n\x01b") do
  "test.txt"
  |> File.stream!()
  |> Stream.map(& &1)
  |> Enum.reduce("", & &2 <> &1)
end
#⇒ <<97, 0, 10, 1, 98>>
```

That said, you might better opt-in for delegating the job to the existing helpers like [`Plug.Conn.send_file/5`](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Conn.html#send_file/5). If you still want to reimplement this functionality, you should use [`iodata`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/typespecs.html#built-in-types) built-in type to construct your object, it’s faster than binaries (and [`Plug.Conn.send_resp/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Conn.html#send_resp/3) happily accepts it.)

Splitting and re-concatenating binaries would not make it run any faster.

Answer (score 1):

From https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/File.html#stream!/3:

```
File.stream!(path, modes \\ [], line_or_bytes \\ :line)
```

> The line_or_bytes argument configures how the file is read when streaming, by :line (default) or by a given number of bytes. When using the :line option, CRLF line breaks (" ") are normalized to LF (" ").

So, by default, it treats the file as text and normalizes line breaks. This makes the result smaller.

Try something like the following instead:

```
File.stream!(fullpath, [], 128 * 1024)
```